# How does one execute a CONDITIONAL push-to-array (on Pine Script)?

Tags: arrays, conditional-statements, pine-script

I'm trying to get data entries pushed into an array in queue format when certain condition(s) are in place.

Keeping it simple, populating an array [of size 20] with price values whenever *volume == volume[1]*, I've tried the following:

```
//@version=4
study(title="ConditionalArrayPush", overlay = false)

var dataset = array.new_float(20)
array.shift(dataset) //storing datapoints FIFO

if (volume == volume[1])
    array.push(dataset, close)

sampleoutput = array.min(dataset)
plot(sampleoutput, "Test", color.white)
```

Script wont run.
Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pine treats an array of `na` values the same as an empty array. If you add a new value first before removing the oldest value then on the first bar where the condition is true and the array is all `na` values you won't run into this problem by doing it in this order.

Also your condition of `volume == volume[1]` is likely to never occur, so it's likely nothing would have ever been added to the array.

```
//@version=4
study(title="ConditionalArrayPush", overlay = false)

var dataset = array.new_float(20)

if volume >= volume[1]
    array.push(dataset, close)
    array.shift(dataset)
    
sampleoutput = array.min(dataset)
plot(sampleoutput, "Test", color.white)
```